# Alteração de Segurança da aplicação para Medium Trust

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, segurança

Recentemente subi um sistema que criei em Asp.Net usando MVC e Entity para o servidor web da KingHost. Em localhost e no meu próprio servidor ela funciona normalmente. Ao tentar acessar a aplicação no servidor da KingHost, dá o seguinte erro:

> [SecurityException: Falha na solicitação da permissão de tipo
>   'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.]
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission
>   cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.get_ApplicationID() +62
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext..ctor() +63
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +30 
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +70
>   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target,
>   Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
>   context) +106
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +418
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296

Pesquisando eu pude perceber o seguinte: No servidor pode-se configurar as políticas de segurança no Web.config que está no diretório %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework{version}\CONFIG\ do servidor (até em localhost vc pode definir isso). Normalmente está assim:

```
<location allowOverride="true">
  <system.web>
    <securityPolicy>
      <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal" />
      <trustLevel name="High" policyFile="web_hightrust.config" />
      <trustLevel name="Medium" policyFile="web_mediumtrust.config" />
      <trustLevel name="Low" policyFile="web_lowtrust.config" />
      <trustLevel name="Minimal" policyFile="web_minimaltrust.config" />
      <trustLevel name="Custom" policyFile="web_CustomTrust.config" />
    </securityPolicy>
    <trust level="Full" originUrl="" /> <--aqui eu digo o nível que as app vão usar-->>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

A minha aplicação por default foi criada como Full Trust. Como o servidor da KingHost está definido como Medium Trust, no web.config da minha aplicação eu só precisaria setar o nível de segurança da minha aplicação para Medium, colocando esse bloco:

```
<system.web>    
    <trust level="Full"/> 
</system.web>
```

Porém, no servidor da KingHost eles definiram o "allowOverride=false", não permitindo que a aplicação escolha qual nível de segurança ela quer utilizar através do Web.config. Da pra ver isso porque após eu colocar esse código aparece essa outra mensagem de erro:

> Esta seção de configuração não pode ser usada neste caminho. Isso
>   ocorre quando o administrador do site bloqueia o acesso a essa seção
>   usando `<location allowOverride="false">` de um arquivo de configuração
>   herdado.

Alguém sabe como eu posso alterar a minha aplicação para Medium Trust?

Comment: Não conheço o painel da KingHost. Você teria acesso às configurações do IIS por alguma coisa como um Remote Desktop, por exemplo?

Comment: O que especificamente você quer saber? Posso abrir um chamado perguntando @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Você está usando alguma DLL baixada da internet? Normalmente elas vêm com uma espécie de bloqueio pelo sistema de arquivos. É preciso desbloquear as DLLs entrando nas propriedades dela.

Comment: As DLL que uso são do EntityFramework, Identity, Owin, Json, Mvc, e Razor basicamente. Não baixei nenhuma dll diferente. E todas essas foram acrescentadas na criação do meu projeto @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez dá uma olhada no erro (acrescentei o erro todo agora). Acho que tem algo a ver com permissões do Owin. Eu uso Entity Framework 6

Comment: Entendi. Não tenho boas notícias pra você: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18154797/1314276

Comment: Alessandro Barros seria possível descrever melhor esses dois passos? 1.baixar os fontes de Itextsharp e XMLworkerHelper 2.acrescentei a seguinte linha [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()] no arquivo AssemblyInfo.cs.

Comment: @SydinhoFranco no fim como ficou? estou tendo o mesmo problema. Se puder ajudar te agradeço

Comment: @LucasVenturella não teve jeito, tive que mudar de servidor. Fui pra o GoDaddy e lá funcionou de boa.

Comment: @SydinhoFranco valeu cara. Eu acabei abrindo um chamado, eles tentaram resolver e não conseguiram e acabaram liberando o full trust pra mim (na kinghost tbm)

Comment: ahhh já estão liberando o Full Trust é? Bom saber @LucasVenturella Valeuu!

Answer (score 2):

Para Frameworks mais novos, a Microsoft está desencorajando o *Medium Trust* em prol do isolamento por nível de sistema operacional, [conforme descrito neste ítem de suporte](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2698981) para Frameworks mais novos como o Owin, no seu caso. Há várias respostas do SO falando sobre isso, mas cito as minhas fontes de pesquisa.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18154797/1314276
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause/17218344#17218344

Ou é preciso negociar com o provedor uma permissão para *Full Trust*, ou trocar de provedor.

Comment: Pesquisando achei isso também =/
Vou tentar negociar com o servidor pra ver se colocar num Full Trust, senão vou mudar de hospedagem.

Comment: A questão é: mudar pra qual hospedagem ? A locaweb e o UOL Host não permitem Full Trust. Estou procurando outros provedores de hospedagem. Alguém sabe de algum?

Comment: @JonePolvora [Veja o Wiki da tag ASP.NET MVC](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-mvc/info). Lá tem algumas sugestões de provedores de hospedagem.

Answer (score 2):

Eu também tive o mesmo problema, descobri que era o Itextsharp que causava esse erro, minha solução foi a seguinte:

- baixar os fontes de Itextsharp e XMLworkerHelper
- acrescentei a seguinte linha `[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()]` no arquivo **AssemblyInfo.cs**.

São orientações da própria Microsoft